# Koala Testusers create_network

Tags: koala

According to the Koala wiki ( https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Test-Users ), creating a network of friends is extremely  simply with the method "create_network"

The example shown:
@test_users.create_network(10, installed_status, permissions)
=> hash_of_10_users

This would be great if I can do this and avoid the Graph API for now.
I attempted to use this method (via irb, after sending secret & appid) with the command
@test_users.create_network(3, false, "")

The console returned the message:
TestUsers#befriend requires hash arguments for both users with id and access_token

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this method only works if "installed_status" = true.

This is referenced at http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/k/koala-1.4.0/Koala/Facebook/TestUsers.html
and I confirmed this with my own experiment
I will attempt to add that comment to the Wiki.